# How to display users as localhost:3000:/:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

How to display users as `localhost:3000/:id` instead of `localhost:3000/users/:id`

And how to correctly redirect to new route?

I use mongoid 4.0.0, rails 4.1.5, devise 3.3.0 and mongoid_slug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

*route.rb*

```
resources :users, only: :index
resources :users, except: :index, path: '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/routes.rb` file put

```
get '/:id', to: 'users#show'
```